# IndexedDB and many-to-many Relationships

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

How are you all handling many-to-many relationships in IndexedDB?

For example, say I have a `Blog` object to hold a blog post and a `Tag` object for a tag/label of the blog post. One `Blog` can have many `Tag`s and one `Tag` can be used by many `Blog`s.

I would create a `blog store` and `tag store` (though I'm open to suggestions) to house the two types of objects:

```
// ...
var blogStore = db.createObjectStore("blog", {keyPath: "blogId", autoIncrement: true});
blogStore.createIndex("title", "title", {unique: true});
var tagStore = db.createObjectStore("tag", {keyPath: "tagId", autoIncrement: true});
tagStore.createIndex("label", "label", {unique: true});
```

Off hand I can think of two ways to link the two:

1. have a `Blog.tags` which would be an array of `BlogTag` objects which holds `blogId` and `tagId` (and would also be in the store for retrieval) or
2. have a `Blog.tags` which would be an array of `tagId`s that could be used to look up the `Tag`s.

The first way seems longer-winded but is how this would be tackled in SQL. Is that just SQL-baggage that I should leave behind?

I suppose a 3rd way would be to have `Blog.tags` be an array of `Tag`s. This seems simplest but then I couldn't query for `Tag`s or reuse tags across blogs (or could I?).

Has anyone else handled such a situation with indexedDB? If so, what did you end up doing? What were some pitfalls?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm working on an [IndexedDB-backed JS neural network implementation](https://github.com/editor/Neural/) and faced this very 
problem.

We don't have joins in IndexedDB so you're looking at at least two object store hits unless you're doing some sort of memoization/caching.

From experience I've found that a document-oriented style is best with IndexedDB objects (store everything in the same store), but a secondary store is needed to house relations.

Here's what I'm doing.

Say you want to have a local store of actors and movies -- something like IMDB. This and most any many-to-many relationship can be modeled with IndexedDB using two tables: Objects and Relationships.

Here are the two tables. You'd want key lookups* on almost everything. Anything that doesn't say unique can be non-unique.

Objects object store:

```
type_id*
whatever*..
```

Relationships object store:

```
id* (unique, auto-incrementing)
from_type*
to_id*
```

An actor/movie example would be two records in the Objects table and one in the relationship table:

```
var actor1 = {
    id: 'actor_jonah_goldberg',
    display: 'Jonah Goldberg',
};

var actor2 = {
    id: 'actor_michael_cera',
    display: 'Michael Cera'
};

var movie1 = {
    id: 'movie_superbad',
    display: 'Superbad',
    year: 2007
};

var movie2 = {
    id: 'movie_juno',
    display: 'Juno',
    year: 2007
};

//relationship primary key ids are auto-inc

var relationship1 = {
    from_id: 'actor_jonah_goldberg',
    to_id: 'movie_superbad'
} 

var relationship2 = {
    from_id: 'actor_michael_cera',
    to_id: 'movie_superbad'
} 

var relationship3 = {
    from_id: 'actor_michael_cera',
    to_id: 'movie_juno'
}
```

Psuedo-code for getting Michael Cera's movies:

```
IndexedDBApp( { 'store': 'relationships', 'index': 'from_id', 'key': 'actor_michael_cera', 'on_success': function( row ) {...} );
// Would return movie_superbad and movie_juno rows on_success
```

Psuedo-code for getting all movies from a given year:

```
IndexedDBApp( { 'store': 'objects', 'index': 'year', 'key': 2007, 'on_success': function( row ) {...} );
// Would return movie_superbad and movie_juno rows on_success
```

Psuedo-code for getting a movie's actors:

```
IndexedDBApp( { 'store': 'relationships', 'index': 'to_id', 'key': 'movie_superbad', 'on_success': function( row ) {...} );
// Would return actor_jonah_goldberg and actor_michael_cera on_success
```

Psuedo-code for getting all actors:

```
IndexedDBApp( { 'store': 'relationships', 'index': 'id', 'cursor_begin': 'actor_a', 'cursor_end': 'actor_z', 'on_success': function( row ) {...} );
// Would return actor_jonah_goldberg and actor_michael_cera on_success
```